# Unexpected token error on namespaced knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Building a simple app with Knockout, and I ran into a bug I don't fully understand.

Given these bindings:

```
var bindings = {
    employee: {
        name: ko.observable("Employee Name"),
        address: ko.observable("Employee Address")
    },

    ...
};

ko.applyBindings(bindings);
```

I can set up `<input data-bind="value: employee.name">` without issue. The trouble starts when I try to wrap employee in another object:

```
var bindings = {
    case: {
        name: ko.observable("Case Name"),

        employee: {
            name: ko.observable("Employee Name"),
            address: ko.observable("Employee Address")
        }
    },

    ...
};

ko.applyBindings(bindings);
```

Trying to set up `<input data-bind="value: case.employee.name">` returns an error `Unexpected token: case`. Is this some kind of limitation within Knockout itself, or am I overlooking something obvious? Googling "Unexpected token error knockout" (and its variants) doesn't return any useful results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` is a reserved word. When knockout tries to generate the binding function, the `case` word will not be understood by the js engine and will generate that error. Use another -not reserved- word.

Comment: Really should have caught that - I need more coffee. Thanks for the quick response!